# How would you implement a vstack and hstack inside a tableview with both SwiftUI & UIKit?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am creating a dating app and am trying to place a vstack and hstack inside a table view cell but nothing displays. Im not getting any errors. Can you implement the two? If so is there something Im missing? Thanks in advance.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { return 1 }
            
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { return 1 }
            
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     


let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! DiscoverCell


VStack {
    
ZStack{

ForEach(Card.data.reversed()) { card in
        
CardView(card: card)

}

}
.padding(8)

.zIndex(1.0)
}

self.tableView.rowHeight = 493
        
return cell as DiscoverCell
```

Comment: That doesn’t work. You can only mix UIKit and SwiftUI via UIViewControllerRepresentsble, UIViewRepresentable or UIHostingController. You need one of those three to make them compatible with eachother.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out using UIHostingController